# Storing audio files in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql

How to store audio files to a MySQL database from a Java servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload audio files to Java servlet. Java servlet accept audio files and store audio files in your local computer. then you can get the relative path of audio files, you save this path to a database, anytime you can get audio files by finding the record of database.

Comment: This may be the start of a good answer, but could you provide a little more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).